# Is it possible to use django-rest-framework 3.x `ListSerializer` without overriding `get_serializer`?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've made a `RawMeasurementSerializer` and a `RawMeasurementListSerializer` (subclassing `ListSerializer`) which all work as expected.

The documentation says I shouldn't use the `ListSerializer` directly but rather instantiate the singular serializer with the `many=True` argument.

So I'm forced to override `get_serializer` in my view:

```
class RawMeasurements(CreateAPIView):                                            

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = RawMeasurementSerializer
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return RawMeasurementSerializer(many=True, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is basically identical to the DRF implementation in `generics.py`, bar the `many=True`. I would prefer not to re-implement bits of DRF where possible.

Is there a better way, can I do something like this?

```
class RawMeasurements(CreateAPIView):                                            
    serializer_class = RawMeasurementSerializer
    use_list_serializer = True
```

So far my best attempt is this:

```
from functools import partial

class RawMeasurements(CreateAPIView):                                            
    serializer_class = partial(RawMeasurementSerializer, many=True)
```

This works, but doesn't feel very pythonic to me!

Thanks, Paul

Comment: I love the use of `partial`!  It's quite pythonic, though slightly odd to see for a class.  How come you're using a many=True on a Create endpoint?  It's kind of defeating the generics to use an endpoint to create a list of resources.

Comment: Interesting - how come you think so @KevinStone? I was previously writing all the `post` view logic and serializer `save`, `create`, `update` etc myself. I found that switching to a `CreateAPIView` allowed me to remove all that and only implement a `serializer.update()` that uses `update_or_create`. TBH the move from DRF 2 to 3 has confused me so I may well be using it inappropriately!

Answer (score -1):

How about rewriting the `get_serializer_class` in GenericAPIView?

```
from functools import partial

class SetManyMixin:
    def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = super().get_serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
        return partial(serializer_class, many=True)
```

Then use the mixin class:

```
class RawMeasurements(SetManyMixin, CreateAPIView):                                            
    serializer_class = RawMeasurementSerializer
```

Comment: This feels quite elegant to me, I'm interested to know what others think?

Comment: I would override `get_serializer` then, not `get_serializer_class`.